# Ocaml Syntax Efficiency

Tags: syntax, ocaml

So this is a user defined datatype day of each day of the week (ie: Sunday, Monday, etc.)

```
let is_weekend_day (d:day) : bool = 
   begin match d with
     | Sunday -> true
     | Saturday -> true 
     | _ -> false
   end
```

Is there any way to condense the code?

```
ie: Sunday || Saturday -> true 

the problem with this is that it's not in syntax, but having 2 additional       
lines seems like such a waste of space!
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can combine patterns using `|`, that is called a [or-pattern](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/patterns.html#sec108).

By using it and removing superfluous type annotations and begin/end you get the following:

```
let is_weekend_day d = 
   match d with
     | Sunday | Saturday -> true 
     | _ -> false
```

Answer (score 2):

You can in fact write this:

```
let is_weekend_day = function
    | Sunday | Saturday -> true
    | _ -> false
```

Or this:

```
let is_weekend_day = ListLabels.mem ~set: [Saturday;Sunday];;
```

If you want to get fancy you can define a function that lifts an operator from operating on booleans to operating on functions that return boolean:

```
let lift op f g x = op (f x) (g x)
```

Then you can define is_weekend_day like this:

```
let is_weekend_day = lift (||) ((=) Saturday) ((=) Sunday)
```

It reads even more nicely if you make `lift (||)` into an operator:

```
let (|||) a b = lift (||) a b

let is_weekend_day = ((=) Saturday) ||| ((=) Sunday)

let is_mwf = ((=) Monday) ||| ((=) Wednesday) ||| ((=) Friday)
```

OCaml syntax is flexible.

Comment: All your versions after the first one are less efficient and have less static checking, you shouldn't advise them.